# List into XML then Reading XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

So far i have wrote to a XML storing a list and some other valuable information through passing it through a constructor and saving it as so:

```
 RoundEdit._quizStruct.Add(new RoundEdit(quizId, roundId, roundName, QuestionsCount, Questions));
```

This is the constructor and what not.

```
public RoundEdit()
        {
            quizStruct = new List<RoundEdit>();
        }
        public RoundEdit(int inQuizID, int inRoundId,string inRoundName, int inNumOfQuestions, List<int> inRoundQuestions)
        {
            QuizId = inQuizID;
            RoundId = inRoundId;
            roundName = inRoundName;
            numOfQuestions = inNumOfQuestions;
            roundQuestions = inRoundQuestions;

        }

        public static void saveRounds()
        {
            SaveXmlQuiz.SaveData(_quizStruct, "rounds.xml");
        }
```

this is then the xml file i am trying to read from and de serialize.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfRoundEdit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <RoundEdit>
    <_quizId>0</_quizId>
    <_roundId>1</_roundId>
    <_roundName>1</_roundName>
    <_numOfQuestions>2</_numOfQuestions>
    <_roundQuestions>
      <int>2</int>
      <int>3</int>
    </_roundQuestions>
  </RoundEdit>
  <RoundEdit>
    <_quizId>0</_quizId>
    <_roundId>2</_roundId>
    <_roundName>2</_roundName>
    <_numOfQuestions>2</_numOfQuestions>
    <_roundQuestions>
      <int>2</int>
      <int>3</int>
    </_roundQuestions>
  </RoundEdit>
</ArrayOfRoundEdit>
```

but when i use this method

```
XmlSerializer xs; FileStream read; RoundEdit info; 
            xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RoundEdit));
            read = new FileStream("rounds.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            try
            {
                info = (RoundEdit)xs.Deserialize(read);//exception here for john to look at
                RoundList.Add(new RoundEdit(info._quizId, info._roundId, info._roundName, info._numOfQuestions, info._roundQuestions));
            }
```

I get the error of There is an error in XML document (2, 2), I think it is cause of how it is reading in the list that was stored of the roundQuestions but i am not sure if anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the `XDocument` class like this:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
var roundEditXmlArr = xDoc.Element("ArrayOfRoundEdit").Elements("RoundEdit").ToArray(); // array or list but you know the exact number
```

Now you have an array with your needed elements in it. Now you can read the information out of the items:

```
List<RoundEdit> roundEditList = new List<RoundEdit>();

for (var i = 0; i < roundEditXmlArr.Length; i++)
{
   var roundEdit = new RoundEdit(roundEditXmlArr[i].Element("_quizId").Value, [...]);
   roundEditList.Add(roundEdit);
}
```

This code is only for an example - the implementation sure could be better and should be.

Sorry i have no experience with the `XmlSerializer` so i can't say where exactly the problem is.